# Which register does jnz check

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following toy example of assembly code that illustrates the use of `jnz`. My question is: In the code below, what does jnz checks to decides if it is `0` or not ? I ran the code and it appears to me it checks `cx` register. I am not sure from this point. For example, if I have a `cmp` and `cx`, what does `jnz` checks? `cx` or `cmp` result?

```
mov cx, 5
mov ax, 0
mov bx, 200
add ax, bx
inc bx
dec cx
jnz 0109
int 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks zero flag in status (FLAGS) register. 
To see which instructions modify this flag, see [x86 software developers manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

It says this about DEC:

> Flags Affected
>
> The CF flag is not affected. The OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags are set
>   according to the result.

So, JNZ checks flag set by previous instruction that happens to modify it and in your case it's dec.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DEC` instruction](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#dec) modifies the flags word, so the conditional jump acts on the result of the `DEC`, which happens to be written to `cx`.

The `CMP` instruction is technically the same thing as `SUB`, with the only difference that the result is not stored but only the flags are modified.

Answer (score 0):

The JNZ opcode checks for the status of zero flag . so among DEC cx and CMP, the one which is written after will have its effect on the flag. so the one which is written after will decide the operation for JNZ.